# SIGSEGV error while debugging in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I run into a debugging error in Qt Creator, even on very simple programs.
When I launch the debugger from Qt Creator, it stops on lines where no breakpoint has been specified, and the program crashes with a SIGSEV (Segmentation fault) when asked to continue.

No such error appears when the Release version is ran.

I managed to reproduce the error with a minimalist example, which seems to indicate that the problem does not come from the code.
Here is an illustration of the problem with this minimalist example:

[image: Debug error]

And the code I used to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Configuration used:

- Windows 7 64bits
- Qt Creator 4.2.1 (Community)
- Qt 5.8.0 (compiled with the following compiler)
- MinGW 5.3.0 32bit compiler
- GNU gdb 7.10.1 for MinGW 5.3.0 32bit

EDIT: Maybe it's an indication, the following messages appear in the console while debugging:

```
Beginning of debugging
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shell32.dll"
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\user32.dll"
End of debugging
```

Comment: Are you running Debug version from opened Qt Creator? Are you using the same MinGW compiler to build application that was used to build Qt and distributed together with Qt build (this MinGW binaries resides in Qt installation directory, if you haven't unchecked this option during Qt installation)

Comment: @MaxGo Yes, and yes. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: And are you using Qt Creator installed along with this Qt MinGW build?

Comment: have you tried to "Clean All" in the Menu "Build" in QtCreator and rebuild your application?

Comment: @J-Mik Yes, that did not help.

Comment: @MaxGo I am not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if the kit I am using is the one I described in the question? If so, yes it is. I have a MSVC compiler installed but the one used is the MinGW.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois, each Qt SDK installer should provide it's own prebuilt version of Qt Creator. You should be able to find it inside folder with Qt. When you launch Qt Creator installed along with SDK, PATH variable already configured to work exactly with installed SDK. It seems that your issue possible related to cofiguration of your PATH. Using of Qt Creator installed along with Qt should answer the question if the issue is with PATH

Comment: @MaxGo I checked, the Qt Creator I used is the one provided in the Qt 5.8 build...

Comment: you have wrote "When I launch the debugger " ... is it crashing only when you run with attached debugger, or it's crashing even if you run debug build without debugger attached?

Comment: @MaxGo Only with debugger attached

Comment: oh, okay, so the issue is related to used debugger compatibility. this happened for me sometime too. it seems I have tried to find another debugger, but not sure what is wrong with gdb on WIndows here